# Google Reporting API return event actions for category

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I'm trying to return all given actions for a particular event category via my Node JS application that's fetching data from the Google Reporting API V3. I'm able to fetch everything with...

```js
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwt,
    'ids': `ga:${viewId}`,
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'dimensions': 'ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction',
    'metrics': 'ga:uniqueEvents'
  })

  res.send(result)
})
```

But as soon as I add a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) it doesn't work, no data is returned despite the 200 status code:

```js
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwt,
    'ids': `ga:${viewId}`,
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'filters': 'ga:eventCategory==Honeycomb:%20Core',
    'dimensions': 'ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction',
    'metrics': 'ga:uniqueEvents'
  })

  res.send(result)
})
```

From my understanding, spaces have to be encoded, which is what I've done, but no data is returned, am I missing something? My event category is called: `Honeycomb: Core` in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Try `'filters': 'ga:eventCategory%3D%3DHoneycomb:%20Core'`

Look at the table of filter operators in the reference link you posted. The "==" should be encoded as well.